# how to solve InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in) while running spark application?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

When running Spark application with DSE 5.0.5:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount");
                JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        // Load our input data.
        JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile(inputFile);
        // Split up into words.
        JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(
          new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
              return Arrays.asList(x.split(" "));
            }});
        // Transform into word and count.
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(
          new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>(){
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String x){
              return new Tuple2(x, 1);

    }});
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>(){ public Integer call(Integer x, Integer y){ return x + y;}});

        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> output = counts.collect();
        for (Tuple2<?,?> tuple : output) {
          System.out.println(tuple._1() + ": " + tuple._2());
        }
```

I get following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4699684c rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@39bfefb[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:122)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:411)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.reduceByKey(JavaPairRDD.scala:526)
    at com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.initialize(CassandraProxyClient.java:486)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.<init>(CassandraProxyClient.java:404)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.newProxyConnection(CassandraProxyClient.java:283)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.access$000(CassandraProxyClient.java:50)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient$Builder.newProxyConnection(CassandraProxyClient.java:237)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.connectToCassandra(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:373)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.initialize(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:269)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystem.initialize(CassandraFileSystem.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:656)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$describe_keyspaces_result$describe_keyspaces_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:33226)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$describe_keyspaces_result$describe_keyspaces_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:33193)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$describe_keyspaces_result.read(Cassandra.java:33135)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_keyspaces(Cassandra.java:1222)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_keyspaces(Cassandra.java:1210)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.initialize(CassandraProxyClient.java:453)
    ... 55 more:
```

Comment: following is code snippet:

Comment: do you have authentication enabled on the cluster?